# How to import a hashtable into powershell to match existing format

Tags: arrays, powershell, windows-10, hashtable, powershell-4.0

TLDR: How would I import this hashtableto use in the code below?

I am working on making a script I wrote modular so that I can change the variables quickly. The script currently references:

```
$MenuGroups = @{
    "1. Internet & Network tools" = "Microsoft Edge", "Internet Explorer"
    "2. Microsoft Office" = "Excel 2016","Outlook 2016","PowerPoint 2016","Publisher 2016","Word 2016"
    "3. Text, file & programming tools" = "Calculator","Notepad++"
    "4. Media tools" = "XBOX", "NONE"
    "5. Scientific software" = "Calculator"
    "6. Administrator" = "Control Panel"
    "7. Other tools" = "Search Google", "Store locator"
}
```

To be used by the following code segment:

```
foreach ($MenuGroup in $MenuGroups.Keys | Sort-Object) {
    # Init xml element for software group
    $SoftwareGroupXml = $StartMenuXml.CreateElement("start","Group", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout")
    $SoftwareGroupXml.SetAttribute('Name',$MenuGroup.Substring(3))
    # Init row and col
    $col = 0
    $row = 0
    # Looping all software links in start menu
    foreach ($Software in $MenuGroups[$MenuGroup]) {
        # Check if it is time for a new col
        if (($col%($NumCol-1) -eq 1) -and ($col -ne 1)) {
            $row +=2
            $col = 0
        }
```

I am trying to replace the $MenuGroups hashtable with a file that I can swap as needed. I have tried to place the text in a text file and used the following code:`$MenuGroups = Get-content "C:\Menugroups.txt"` but my output is blank. I tried it as a CSV as well but it is still blank. When I run the get content on both the CSV and TXT files on their own the content shows up in powershell. I know I'm missing something small. How would I properly import this from a CSV, TXT or XML to match this code?

However, I'm a little confused as to why I couldn't just use '$MenuGroups = @(Get-Content -Path C:\MenuGroups.txt | Out-String) | ConvertFrom-StringData)' and why that doesn't work. The issue is that I'm trying to use the existing code with what I import.

I have tried exporting the hashtable to JSON and then using that with an import command. When I test to see if the data is there I am greeted with my data but when I try to use it my script is returning blanks on me.

Any help is appreciated and welcome! If more information is needed please let me know and I will update immediately.

Comment: Well, first of all, $MenuGroups is a hashtable not an array. Second, to create that hashtable from a file you would need to read the file `Get-Content` then you would need to parse what you read and assign key and values in the hashtable. To do that you would want to have the data structured in the file somehow. For this situation a JSON file comes to mind.

Comment: Is it not possible to just enter the data as I have it structured already? I thought it would be easier to just insert the data? To add labels would mean re-writing the whole script. I'm trying to avoid that if possible. As always your help is truly appreciated!

Comment: You ***could*** save a file with exactly what you have right there. Thenyou could dot source that file at the beginning of your script. I'm not real sure what that gains you over just editing the script if the data changes though.

Comment: Just put the code for the hashtable inside a text file, then run Get-Content | Invoke-Expression /s

Comment: @JacobColvin I'm getting errors when I run `$MenuGroups = get-content C:\MenuGroups.txt | Invoke-Expression /s` Am I missing something? The error is Invoke-Expression : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its 
properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.

Comment: I was just joking that you could arbitrarily execute the text file which I don't recommend. Actually kind of the same thing EB suggested. Why not just pipe your object to ConvertTo-JSON and then back ConvertFrom-JSON?

Comment: Ok so that works to bring the data back in but it breaks everything down stream in the code. I am still getting blank outputs. Any tips are appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So let me regroup and refocus here. Is there not an easier way to import a txt file and put each line into a hash table like I did in my original code?

Comment: Can you post how you want your .txt file to look?

Comment: `"1. Internet & Network tools" = "Microsoft Edge", "Internet Explorer"
    "2. Microsoft Office" = "Excel 2016","Outlook 2016","PowerPoint 2016","Publisher 2016","Word 2016"
    "3. Text, file & programming tools" = "Calculator","Notepad++"
    "4. Media tools" = "XBOX", "NONE"
    "5. Scientific software" = "Calculator"
    "6. Administrator" = "Control Panel"
    "7. Other tools" = "Search Google", "Store locator"`

Comment: However, I'm a little confused as to why I couldn't just use `$MenuGroups = @(Get-Content -Path C:\MenuGroups.txt | Out-String) | ConvertFrom-StringData)` and why that doesn't work. The issue is that I'm trying to use the existing code with what I import.

Comment: Please update your question with this information rather than using comments.